# Grails disable _action_name defining action

Tags: grails

My url mapping

```
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        controller = "public"
        action = "show404"
    }
```

If request is get all fine but if post with _action_name param controller metod name runned.
How disable this?

Comment: This question does not make sense. Why are you catching all possible controller/action combinations with and single controller and action hard wired? I have no idea what you mean by "controller metod name runned".

Comment: Post parametr _action_NAME will run controller action NAME, not show404 action